Makefile help target
I am trying to create a nice and dynamic help, but I am struggling to interpret the variable name in the project's .env file. I need these names to be interpreted by the .env. I will provide the closest result I was able to achieve, but I couldn't make any further progress.

In the image above, I marked the text that needs to be interpreted by the .env
Here is the code:
SHELL := /bin/bash
include .env

ENV_FILE = .env

help:  ## Show help.
    @awk 'BEGIN { \
        FS = ":.*##"; \
        printf "\nUsage:\n  make \033[0;34m<target>\033[0m\n\nTargets:\n" \
    } \
    /^[a-zA-Z_\/\-\$${}]+:.*?##/ { \
        targetName = $$1; \
        description = $$2; \
        if (match(targetName, "\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}")) { \
            varEnvName = substr(targetName, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2); \
            gsub("\\$$\\{[a-zA-Z_]+\\}", varEnvName, targetName); \
        }; \
        printf "  \033[0;34m%-10s\033[0m %s\n", targetName, description \
    }' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)

call/${DOCKER_PHP_CONTAINER_NAME}/a: ## PHP // Help dynamic.
    @echo "Dynamic target running for ${DOCKER_PHP_CONTAINER_NAME}"

call/${DOCKER_NGINX_CONTAINER_NAME}/a: ## NGINX // Help dynamic.
    @echo "Dynamic target running for ${DOCKER_NGINX_CONTAINER_NAME}"

call/bpro_php/b: ## Help fixed.
    @echo "Fixed target running..."


.*? in one of your regexps in your awk script is undefined behavior in an ERE (it's a PCRE construct, I think) so what any awk does with that is up to whoever provides that version of awk but whatever it does, it's not what you hoped it'd do. You're also requiring more escapes than necessary in your regexps as you're using string "..." instead of regexp /.../ delimiters in match() and gsub(). Get a script working outside of the makefile first, then convert it as needed to run in the makefile.

Don't post images (or links) as we can't copy/paste an image to test with. Only post text and make sure to show both the same input and the associated expected output given that input.

@EdMorton Hi buddy, How have you been?
Sorry, i'm a learning and i'm not good on awk, so sometimes i need to use chatGPT to help.
About image, i just put output on image, the Makefile script is bellow, if you want, i just copy and paste in a file called Makefile, and run like:
make help
Thanks for your time :)

ChatGPT is OK to get a starting point but it's almost always wrong so don't assume anything it tells you will be correct. My suggestion was to write an awk script to do what you want and THEN to try to call it in your makefile. If you do that then you won't have to worry about both things at the same time. Also add the expected output.

You have (at least) two problems.  First, you haven't actually sourced the .env file in your shell script.  You don't show us what the contents of the .env file are, but unless they are exported (and this would be unusual in my experience) they aren't passed to the shell that runs recipes.  Seocnd, there's nothing in your awk script that actually looks up the variable in the environment.  Your gsub is just replacing the variable references ${FOO} with the string of the variable name, e.g. FOO.  You have to use that string as an environment variable and replace its value.

Hi @MadScientist thanks your comments.
I change little bit now
mi first line inside the help target is:
set -a; source .env &>/dev/null; set +a; \
This is made the .en is export.
But you second point is too advanced for me :/

I made it :)
I'm not sure if it's a best solution, but it's work for me.
help:  ##           Show help.
@set -a; source .env &>/dev/null; set +a; \
awk -v ENV_FILE=".env" ' \
BEGIN { \
    FS = ":.*##"; \
    printf "\nUsage:\n  make \033[0;34m<target>\033[0m\n\nTargets:\n" \
} \
/^[a-zA-Z_\/\-\$${}]+:.*?##/ { \
    targetName = $$1; \
    description = $$2; \
    while ((getline < ENV_FILE) > 0) { \
        if ($$0 ~ /^[^#[:space:]]/) { \
            gsub(/=.*/, "", $$0); \
            varName = $$0; \
            varValue = ENVIRON[varName]; \
            gsub("\\$\\{" varName "\\}", varValue, targetName); \
            gsub(/\$$/, "", targetName); \
        } \
    } \
    printf "  \033[0;34m%-10s\033[0m %s\n", targetName, description; \
    close(ENV_FILE); \
}' $(MAKEFILE_LIST)


Another way to go, would be to have your help recipe run make -np to ask make to print its database of rules and then parse that output to get the target names you want.  This way make itself will expand the variables just as it will when it runs "for real" and you don't have to replace variables and there's no chance that you'll get the wrong thing.
To do this you'd need to do something like:
_MAKE = $(MAKE)
help:  ## Show help.
        @printf '\nUsage:\n  make \033[0;34m<target>\033[0m\n\nTargets:\n'
        @$(_MAKE) -np | sed -n 's,^\(call/[^:]*\):.*,\1,p'

This will extract all the targets starting with call/ from the output of the make -np call.
If you want to know what the _MAKE stuff is about, it's because of this.
